# LINQ join query destination has List fields

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Good day I have this 2 models

```
public partial class PostPhoto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public int? User { get; set; }
    public Guid? Post { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int? User { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to join this 2 into this ViewModel

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String PostBody { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserFullname { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public List<Images> ImageList { get; set; }
}

public class Images
{
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

}
```

and I have this join query

```
(from post in _context.Post
                     join user in _context.AspNetUsers
                     on post.User equals user.Id
                     join photos in _context.PostPhoto
                     on post.Id equals photos.Post into phtos

                     orderby post.DateCreated descending

                     select new PostViewModel {
                         Id = post.Id,
                         UserId = user.Id,
                         UserFullname = string.Format("{0} {1}", user.Firstname, user.LastName),
                         PostBody = post.Text,
                         DateCreated = (DateTime)post.DateCreated,
                     }).ToList();
```

The problem is I don't know how to populate the `List<Images>` in my result of the join statement.
Is there anyone have the idea on how to that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need JOIN to Photos. Just fill list in projection

```cs
var query = 
    from post in _context.Post
    join user in _context.AspNetUsers on post.User equals user.Id

    orderby post.DateCreated descending

    select new PostViewModel 
    {
        Id = post.Id,
        UserId = user.Id,
        UserFullname = string.Format("{0} {1}", user.Firstname, user.LastName),
        PostBody = post.Text,
        DateCreated = (DateTime)post.DateCreated,
        ImageList = _context.PostPhoto
            .Where(p => post.Id == p.Post)
            .Select(p => new Images { ImagePath = p.Path })
            .ToList()
    };
```

Comment: I never thought that was allowed in join. It works now thanks man!!!